# Put HTML in Joomla 3 Article Caption Field

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I have a site in Joomla 3.x and in it's native **Full Article Image** and **Caption** field I would like to be able to put HTML in the Caption field.

Right now the field strips any html and just displays text. How can I edit joomla to make the caption field edit/output html. I am using the default protostar theme.

http://docs.joomla.org/images/b/ba/Help30-Content-Article-Manager-Edit-screen.png

Answer (score 0):

First you have to change field filter and type in article XML file located in `/administrator/components/com_content/models/forms/article.xml` Then you should check if database field have required length. The last part is checking if there is no additional filtering in those files:

- /administrator/components/com_content/models/article.php
- /administrator/components/com_content/controllers/article.php
- /libraries/legacy/tables/content.php

and of course in files from front-end (article and category models and views)